# Image of a partition of a set through a bijective function is also a partition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a set and $\mathcal{P}$ a partition of $A$ (a partition of a set $A$ is a set of non-empty subsets of $A$ such that every element $x \in A$ is in exactly one of these subsets), and $f:A \to A$ a bijective function. Then, the set $B = \{ f(P) : P \in \mathcal{P} \}$ is also a partition of $A$. Is this true or am I wrong?

Intuitively, I think is true because if $f$
is bijective, then each element of $A$
has a unique correspondent in $A.$
Then, each subset $B⊂A$
has a unique correspondent subset in $A.$ Then, if two or more disjoint subsets of $A$ have unique correspondents in $A,$ because subsets are disjoint, and $f$
is bijective, the correspondents are disjoint. So if we have a partition, image of partition through a bijective function is also a partition. Is this ok?

Comment: @AnneBauval, intuitively, I think is true because if $f$ is bijective, then each element of $A$ has a unique correspondent in $A$. Then, each subset $B \subset A$ has a unique correspondent subset in $A$. Then, if two or more disjoint subsets of A have unique correspondents in A, because subsets are disjoint, and $f$ is bijective, the correspondents are disjoint. So if we have a partition, image of partition through a bijective function is also a partition. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes it is ok intuitively (next time, include such thoughts in your post). To formalize it, denote by $f(B)=\{f(x)\mid x\in B\}$ the "correspondent" of $B$ (unique by definition), and prove that [$\cup_{i\in I}f(B_i)=f(\cup_{i\in I}B_i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397472/image-of-a-union-of-collection-of-sets-as-union-of-the-images) and (using the bijectivity of $f$) that $f(B)\cap f(C)=f(B\cap C).$

Comment: [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693).

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks! So, from this will result that if I have a function $g : \mathcal{P} \to B$ (where $ \mathcal{P}$ and $B$ are the partitions from my question), $g(X) = f(X), X\in\mathcal{P}$, then $g$ is a bijection? Is a true result? Or am I wrong?

Comment: This is a new question (should be another post) but let's go: $g$ is surjective by definition of $B.$ It is injective, and even $G:P(A)\to P(A),X\mapsto f(X)$ is bijective: $G^{-1}(Y)=f^{-1}(Y).$ See [Showing if $f$ is an injection then $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ and if $f$ is onto $Y$ then $B=f(f^{-1}(B))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780788).

Comment: And here $P(A)$ is the set of all partitions of $A$?

Comment: No, it is the set of subsets of $A.$

Comment: Oh. Ok. Now I understand. So the function $g$ is really bijective. Thanks you very much for all help!